# Extract class only text

Tags: python, class, web, extract

I'm trying to solve this.
The extract works perfectly but the result is :

> " div class = " ppl_product_header "" " H1 " Memory 4 Gb Dimm 2133 Mts
>   CL15 " / h1 " " / Div "

but I need only what is between " h1 " and "" h1 "" . ie the text only.

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import urllib2 
 import time
 y=0
 url ="http://www.grupccccco.com.ar/PROcccO/PcccD_ID=3704444/Distrfffdora.aspx"
 html_page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
 x=soup.find_all('div', class_='ppl_product_header')
 print x

print "good bye"
```

Comment: use `print x.text`

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_text()`, in your case - `print x.get_text()`